# Div has black background on ios5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios5, html5-video

I'm making a page where you have a div, a video array, and buttons. The div in question is placed before the `<video>` tag, and shows up black instead of having the background-image that it is set to. I've tried putting the div in different locations, linking the image in CSS or directly, fading the `<video>` in and out, and even putting a poster image for the video so it's not blank. Nothing.

Can I get some help, this has to be done on monday (along with five other things), so I'm very rushed for time.the javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var video = $('#myVid');
    //before everything get started
    video.on('loadedmetadata');

    $('li, .thumbs').on('click', function () {
        $('.thumbs').bind('click', function() {
        $('#MyT').fadeIn(0);
        $('.slider').fadeIn(0);
        $('.timeBar').fadeOut(0);
        });
        var numb = $(this).index(),
            videos = ['images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v', 'images/talking1.m4v', 'images/talking2.m4v'
            ],
            myVideo = document.getElementById('myVid');
            myVideo.src = videos[numb];
            myVideo.load();
    setTimeout(function(){
        myVideo.play();
    }, 200);
    $('#myVid').bind("playing", function() {
        $('#MyT').fadeOut(1000);
        $('.timeBar').delay(250).fadeIn(0);

    });

    $('#myVid').bind("ended", function () {
        $('.slider').fadeOut(0);
        $('.timeBar').fadeOut(0);

    });

});
});
```

the [relevant] CSS is

```
 #bigPic {
        position:absolute;
        background-image:url(images/IMG_08532.jpg);
        margin-left:-8px;   
        margin-top:-16px;
        height:768px;   
        width:1024px;   
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 1024px;  
        height: 768px;
    }
    #myVid{ 
        position:absolute;
        top:0;  
        left:0;
        margin:none;    
        padding:none;

    }
```

and then the html is

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="MyT" class="norm"></div>
    <div id="bigPic">
    <video id="myVid" class="normal" type="m4v" showlogo="false" height="768" width="1024" poster="images/IMG_08532.jpg"/>

</div>
<div class="buttons">
        <div id="content">
            <div class='slider'><div class="control"><div class="progress"><span class="timeBar"></span></div></div></div>
            <ul class='thumbs'>
              <div style="top:0px;"><li rel='1'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></li></div>
              <div style="top:128px;"><li rel='2'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></li></div>
              <div style="top:256px;"<li rel='3'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></li></div>
              <div style="top:384px;"><li rel='4'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></li></div>
              <div style="top:512px;"><li rel='5'><img src="graphics/filler.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></li></div>
              <div style="top:640px;"><li rel='6'><img src="graphics/filler2.png" alt="" width="280" height="128" /></li></div>
            </ul>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*EDIT*It's not the video, I've tried a few things were it's invisible(and also faded out) and then it comes back in on click. It seems that it's actually the the div "myT",but the image links work fine when they are on other divs.
Please someone help!

Comment: Do you have this issue only in iOS5 and not previous versions and/or android?

Comment: @tipycalFlow I haven't tried it in other versions, because it's specifically for that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the big black is the "video" as ios shows it. What I would try is something like: have the div after (not around) the video, with absolute positioning move it over the video. And onclick just hide it. Unfortunatelly you'll have to click again on the video to start, because apple doesn't let you do it from javascript

Comment: Cite: "The div in question is placed before the <video> tag" => it is not before, it is "around" it

Comment: His intent is to show a video preview. It seems he tried setting the `poster` first and when that didn't work, he used the div to encapsulate the video and give that effect. Apparently he didn't explain it well :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tried a number of things like setting the `<video>` poster and setting the image as the background of a `div` enclosing the video but none worked, in all probability, the issue is with the image or the image-path. In short, the image was not found. Ensure that the image path is correct in relative terms and that the image is present at that path.

Comment: if the image wasn't found the div wouldn't be black IMHO

Comment: Yup! It's black probably because the first frame of the video is black or that's the default way to show the video(without a poster) and since the image (I'm guessing) wasn't found, it stays the default way. I'm not sure, haven't worked with video tag before!